Can I use route model binding in channel routes?
I want to use route model binding in channel route via customizing the key (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#customizing-the-key). I've created a channel in route:
Broadcast::channel("users.{product:product_number}", function (User $user, Product $product) {
    return true;
});

But there's an error here:
preg_match(): Compilation failed: syntax error in subpattern name (missing terminator?) at offset 26 {"userId":107,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): preg_match(): Compilation failed: syntax error in subpattern name (missing terminator?) at offset 26

But when I use this syntax:
Broadcast::channel("users.{product}", function (User $user, Product $product) {
    return true;
});

The above code works, but I don't want the channel name to be users.{product.id}, I want it to be users.{product.product_number}.
I know I can do it this way:
Broadcast::channel("users.{productNumber}", function (User $user, $productNumber) {
    $product = Product::whereProductNumber($productNumber)->first();

    return true;
});

But I want to know if there's a way to do it via route model binding.

I don't think it's possible. Please read this https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/broadcasting#authorization-callback-model-binding

Correct me if i'm wrong but it only says here that it does not support "implicit model binding scoping". It didn't say that it doesn't support the custom key binding.

Try clicking the implicit model binding scoping link it will redirect you to the customizing the key part of the routing docs.
